# How to get iso week in SSIS datepart function

Tags: ssis, datepart

I am trying to get iso week for the date '2022/10/17' in SSIS datepart column expression.
I tried the below expression but did not succeeded.

```
(DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("isoww",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)Date_NewFormat)
```

I also tried isowk, iso_week, ISO_WEEK but failed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the following expression:

**DATEPART("ww",  (DT_DBTIMESTAMP) "2022-10-17")**

Please refer to the following link and pictures.

**[*DATEPART (SSIS Expression)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datepart-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)**

[**Depart Name for Week**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaCGy.jpg)

[**Expression**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI0DS.jpg)

Regards,

Lisa

Comment: Hi, I want ISO week not the regular one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this question. to get the iso week from a date in SSIS column expression use the below formula

```
(DT_WSTR,2)((DATEPART("dy",DATEADD("dd",DATEDIFF("dd",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1/1/1753",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)SomeDateHere) / 7 * 7 + 3,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"01/01/1753")) + 6) / 7 )
```

in the above formula only enter you date and keep everything as it is.
DONOT EDIT 1/1/1753

Answer (score 0):

*--Ask if it is monday (dayweek (monday) = 1)*

```
DATEPART("dw",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,1,4) + "-01-01")) == 1 ?
```

*--If it's monday*

```
DATEADD("week",(DT_I2)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,5,2)) - 1,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,1,4) + "-01-01")) :
```

*--If it isn't monday*

```
DATEADD("week",(DT_I2)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,5,2)) - 1,DATEADD("day",8 - (DATEPART("dw",(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,1,4) + "-01-01"))),(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(DimTime,1,4) + "-01-01")))
```